# How to change border color of imageView in table view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any UIImageView variable in your code...

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
[[yourImageView layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[[yourImageView layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
yourImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Here `yourImageView` will be variable that you have in cell...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use custom file for tableView Cell .

Step 1. Create UITableViewCell file .

Step 2. Assign that new created class to the cell.

step 3. In your storyboard add imageView in cell.

step 4. In cell for row at index path after assigning IBOutlet

add this lines :

```
cell.profilepic.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
cell.profilepic.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

When you are trying to give border to the UITableViewCell's ImageView

try this :

```
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fahim Parkar said answer is correct. But sometimes you didn't find border even though you changed border color of uiimageview. why because image is filled by entire uiimageview.

if above code was work, well and good. Otherwise following below steps :
1) take uiview and imageview addsubview to uiview. 
2) change border color to uiview.